# Duplicated results in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have put together a script from various sources, but cannot understand why i am getting duplicated entries in my results..

eg..

I need to check the scheduled tasks on remote servers, and verify which ones didnt complete sucesfully, and then investigate those.

I have a schedulers.csv file, which has two comlumns IP, and Name.

I downloaded the script Get-ScheduledTask.ps1 from https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-Scheduled-tasks-from-3a377294

Works great and does what i needed.

I then wanted to from a list retrieve the servers names, run the above script as a parameter, then get back the scheduled tasks in a csv file.

```
NextRunTime Author  Trigger State   UserId  ComputerName    Name    LastRunTime LastTaskResult  Description NumberOfMissedRuns  Enabled Path
```

The headers for the above script give me Name and LastTaskResult, which is what I wanted to query further.

The LastTaskResult should be 0 if it completed sucesfully, otherwise i would investigate further.

The code i have so far is :

```
$servers = Import-Csv "C:\test\schedulers.csv"

foreach($server in $servers){
    $ServerName = $server.Name
    $ServerAddress = $server.IP       
        Write-Host $ServerName : $ServerAddress
        $importfile = Get-ScheduledTask.ps1 -ComputerName $ServerName
          |Export-Csv -Path c:\test\scheds.csv -NoTypeInformation


        $Lines = Import-Csv "C:\test\scheds.csv"
        ForEach($line in $lines){                 

            $lines | %{
            $TaskName = $_.name
            $taskresult = $_.LastTaskResult                

            if ($_.LastTaskResult -ne "0")  
            {  
                Write-Host $line.LastTaskResult : $_.name : $_.Path 

            }else{

            }
        }
    }             
}
```

There should be 3 results that show, that have a value of 1 in LastTaskResult, but i get about 38 which is the total amount of tasks on the two servers that i am testing on.

the 3 entries are there also as well, plus all the rest..

please can anyone see where i have gone wrong.. Many Thanks

Comment: Inside your loop you loop again with `$lines`? This needs to change `$lines | %{`... More than likely remove it and switch $_ to $line in that loop. There are other changes that should be made as well but that is the flaw that I see. Exporting to CSV to reimport is a waste.

Comment: I also see you not using the data from `$importfile`

Comment: `Import-Csv "C:\test\schedulers.csv" | ForEach-Object{Get-ScheduledTask.ps1 -ComputerName $_.Name} | Where-Object{$_.LastTaskResult -ne "0"}` would be  a simple example. Lacks error prevention but should give you all results that were not successful.

Comment: Hi, Just done that, however, now its showing all the entries from the last servers results, not just the duplicated ones.

Comment: Your example is much cleaner and easier to read, and it works for whati need, just need to pipe it to email and then test.  Thanks, thats a realy eye opener, though i would like to get mines working also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not tested because i don't have your Get-ScheduledTask.ps1, but here's what i might change

```
$servers = Import-Csv "C:\test\schedulers.csv"

foreach ($server in $servers) {
    $ServerName = $server.Name
    $ServerAddress = $server.IP       
    Write-Host $ServerName : $ServerAddress
    $importfile = Get-ScheduledTask.ps1 -ComputerName $ServerName

    $importfile | Export-Csv -Path c:\test\scheds.csv -NoTypeInformation

    foreach ($line in $importfile) {
        if ($line.LastTaskResult -ne '0') {  
            Write-Host $line.LastTaskResult : $line.Name : $line.Path
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, that works just i wanted it. I need to look at that and my original one above, and try to understand the logic of where i was going wrong. 

Am sure others will be use this bit of script in their administration also, Thanks Again

Comment: In your short example above, how would i be able to show just the lastruntime and lasttaskresult .

  Import-Csv "C:\test\schedulers.csv" | ForEach-Object{Get-ScheduledTask.ps1 -ComputerName $_.Name} | Where-Object{$_.LastTaskResult -ne "0"}